# Large memory footprint with OpenGL cubemap

Tags: opengl, memory, textures

I have a skybox composed of 6 texture of 1024x1024. The cubemap works correctly but CodeXL tells me that the cubemap texture takes 110MB. It finds no OpenGL errors.

This is my code of the cubemap generation:

```
static const char*  names[] = { "/right.", "/left.", "/top.", "/bottom.", "/back.", "/front." };
static const GLenum types[] = {
    GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X, GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_X,
    GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Y, GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Y,
    GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Z, GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Z
};

glGenTextures(1, &_id);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, _id);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
{
    SDL_Surface *image = loadImage(path + names[i] + extension);
    if (image == nullptr)
        return false;
    int     format = image->format->Amask ? GL_RGBA : GL_RGB;
    glTexImage2D(types[i], 0, format, image->w, image->h, 0, format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image->pixels);
    SDL_FreeSurface(image);
}
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, 0);
return true;
```

My previous code was based on a atlas texture and take only 25 MB with alpha channel, the cubemap doesn't have one.

Comment: Hmm, ~25MB would be the expectd size for mipmap level 0. With all mipmap levels, it would be ~1/3 bigger. 110MB sounds more like 32 bit per channel, but your code doesn't seem to set that.

Comment: Yes, this doesn't sound right. There's no good reason why it should use much more than 24 MB. It's fairly common for RGB to use the same amount of memory as RGBA. Maybe you can try RGBA just for the heck of it, to see if it has a problem with RGB. It is possible that it will reserve space for mipmaps because it doesn't know if you will have mipmaps or not. But as @derhass calculated, that's still not close to what you're seeing. If you have at least GL 4.2 available, you could try a combination of `glTexStorage2D()` and `glTexSubImage2D()`, and see if that changes anything.

Comment: I already tried in RGBA, it takes just 147MB, not better ^^. I want to stay in 3.3 core. For more information, CodeXL indicates that the cubemap is in 1024x1024 and textures are in RGB with 8 bits per channel.

Comment: The cubemap take only 18.4MB on Intel GPU. I feel that is a bug in Nvidia driver, -_-'.